# AWS SSM Automation: How to gracefully fail in script invoked by aws:executeScript

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I'm running a Python script via AWS Systems Manger in an automation document - also called a runbook. The script is invoked via action [aws:executeScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-action-executeScript.html) and the selected runtime is python3.7.

All available examples only show how to return data from the script. **How could I indicate the script has failed its job?** This appears to be undocumented.

I tried to `sys.exit(1)` and also to `raise Exception('oh noes')`. Both crash the executor. Unfortunately this completely hides all stdout/stderr of the script and leaves me with the message:

> Step fails when it is Poll action status for completion. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/some-path/customer_script.py", line 23, in main sys.exit(1) SystemExit - 1. Please refer to Automation Service Troubleshooting Guide for more diagnosis details.

The handler method expects two arguments (`events` and `context`). Again, it appears completely undocumented what the content of these objects might be. `events` seems to be a dict with the arguments passed to the script. `context` is some object, but according do `dir(context)` there is no useful method on that object that would allow me to return a failed state:

```
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']
```

Comment: Learn anything on this yet?

Comment: Nope. AWS support told me, throwing an error should actually work. I'm quite sure I tested that before but haven't had time to get back to the project yet.

Answer (score 0):

raise Exception should work. Look at the below example.

```
description: ''
schemaVersion: '0.3'
outputs:
  - script.output
mainSteps:
  - name: script
    action: 'aws:executeScript'
    outputs:
      - Name: output
        Selector: '$.Payload[0]'
        Type: String
    inputs:
      Runtime: python3.7
      Handler: script_handler
      Script: |-
        def script_handler(events, context):          
          array = ['a','b','d']
          if 'c' in array:
            return True
          else: 
            raise Exception("c is not there in array")
```